# Want to convert a date from the format"dd-mmm-yyyy" to "yyyy-mm-dd". And here is my code

Tags: android, calendar, date-format

I Want to convert a date from the format"dd-mmm-yyyy" to "yyyy-mm-dd". And here is my code.

```
 public void convertDate(){
    GregorianCalendar todaysDate = (GregorianCalendar) month.clone();   // Its show the error over here.
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.US);
    currentdatestring = df.format(todaysDate.getTime());
    try{
        Date tdate3= df.parse(currentdatestring);
        tdate4=targetDateformat.format(tdate3);
            } 
        catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.e(getPackageName(), e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But the problem is it showing a nullpointer exception . And i am not able to understand the mistake. Please if someone can help ?

Comment: If `month.clone()` is causing the NPE, then it appears `month == null`. Where and when does `month` get assigned a value?

Comment: Yes, that was the only thing. Thank you buddy.

Comment: one of solution is split by (-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
Date cDate = new Date();
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(cDate);
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DateFormat dffrom = new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy");
DateFormat dfto = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");  
Date today = dffrom.parse("7/1/2011");String s = dfto.format(today);
```